# Php Carbon giving different dates for same timezone

Tags: timezone, php-carbon

I have the following two carbon methods. Why are they giving me different time value despite being the same timezone?

```
 Carbon\Carbon::today()->timezone('Europe/London')
 => Carbon\Carbon @1587945600 {#3503
       date: 2020-04-27 01:00:00.0 Europe/London (+01:00),
 }

 Carbon\Carbon::today('Europe/London')
 => Carbon\Carbon @1587942000 {#3516
        date: 2020-04-27 00:00:00.0 Europe/London (+01:00),
 }
```

I understand I'm doing adding the timezone differently in each method but I thought both was suppose to produce the same result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Carbon::today()->shiftTimezone('Europe/London');` to get the result you want, but first, take a look at this:

```php
echo Carbon::now('Europe/London');
echo Carbon::now()->timezone('Europe/London');
```

Both gives the same output, because it's now and it's in London in both case, so it's consecutive events (few microseconds gap) represented with the same timezone.

But:

```php
Carbon::today('Europe/London');
Carbon::today(); // = Carbon::today('GMT');
```

Represent 2 different moments, it's today (start of day) in London and today (start of day) in GMT. And the day (in summer) start 1 hour later in London than in GMT timezone.

Now if you change the timezone of today in GMT, you change only the timezone, not the moment, so you're 1AM in London.